# MS EXCEL MACRO: Add a prefix and suffix to an entire column of cells?

Tags: vba, excel

Data is in *Column **F***.
I need to add *.com/* to the beginning of the word in the cells.
Then add *.JPG* to the very end of every word in the cells.

**In other words:**
`189389439`
**Needs to end up as:**
`.com/189389439.JPG`

Comment: You can use CONCAT for this if you don't require VBA. It's much easier.  `=CONCATENATE(".com/",F1,".JPG")`

Comment: SO i get down-voted to -2 yet I solve my answer, myself.  Thanks, stackoverflow.  Very helpful (sarcasm)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself:

```
Sub JPegMe()
    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Selection
        If Not IsEmpty(myCell) Then _
            myCell = ".com\" & myCell & ".JPG"
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be `VBA`?

If you just put the formula in `G1` (assuming no column header, or it would be in `G2`):

`=".com/" & F1 & ".JPG"`

And copy this down then you will get what you need and then you can just paste special to save the values (if you need to), potentially over the original data and then delete your column G.

Comment: It makes it easier if it is VBA

Answer (score 0):

I would set on cell G1 the formula ' =".com/" & F1 & ".jpg" ' and then expand this formula to all other rows by double clicking in the right down square that appear if you select the G1 cell.